# Create a log file, which format should I choose?

Tags: unicode, utf-8, utf-16, ansi

I am using VC++ 2008. In my application, I need to output the log strings(Unicode strings) into a log file. In the past, the log file is saved as plain text ANSI format. However, if the string is in Japanese, but the current code page is Chinese, then the string will be displayed incorrectly.

I think of using UTF-8 plain text format. However, when the current code page is Chinese, the strings will also be displayed in correctly.

I think of using UTF-16 plain text format. However, it seems that many tools cannot recognize the UTF-16 file correctly, even if a BOM is included in the beginning of the file.

Therefore, I just wonder which format should I choose to put the log strings, so that it can displayed strings in different code pages correctly.

**Update:**

I will write out the string to file in ANSI format, in the current code page in Visual C++ 2008.

Then I will double-click the file in Windows, by default, Windows will use Nodepad to open the text file. So reading the file is by Nodepad.

Comment: Why not just use UTF-8, and always use code page 65001 for display? What problems do you get if you do that?

Comment: @skomisa, If using UTF-8, then if the file is opened under a Chinese system, many characters cannot be recognized.

Comment: OK, but: [1] Are you encoding the data as UTF-8 when it is written? [2] Are you subsequently reading that data as UTF-8? [3] Are you using code page 65001 to display the Chinese UTF-8 text? [4] Are you using a font that can render the Chinese text? If the answer to all those questions is "yes" then it should work, so please give more details about your approach, such as the font used to render the text, how the data is being written and read, etc. As it stands your question is seeking opinion based answers, so you really need to detail your current approach that isn't working.

Comment: @skomisa, (1) Yes, I use UTF-8 encoding to writing strings into the text file. (2) THen I just use Nodepad to open the text file in WinXP(Chinese system) and see incorrect characters. Nodepad is used to read the text file. (3) Nodepad is used to read the file. (4) I am not sure which fonts Nodepad will use, but my Chinese system can display other Chinese characters in other documents correctly. So it should have the fonts.